# Do spells learned from Magic Initiate work with Metamagic?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, metamagic

I have been searching on here and other sites and I can't find the answer. If i were to take Magic Initiate on my sorcerer would I be able to use metamagic on the spells?

Comment: I'll gladly take a duplicate tag if there is already an answer here.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey As far as I know, metamagic only works for sorcerer spells and I don't think magic initiate would make spells not from the sorcerer list into sorcerer spells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, spells learned from Magic Initiate work with Metamagic.

There are no restrictions on Metamagic that state that they can only be used on Sorcerer spells.

If it *were* restricted to only Sorcerer spells, it would say so.

> ### Metamagic
>
> At 3rd level, you gain the ability to twist **your spells** to suit your needs. [...] You can use only one Metamagic option on a spell when you cast it, unless otherwise noted.
>
> #### Careful Spell
>
> When you cast a spell...
>
> #### Distant Spell
>
> When you cast a spell...
>
> #### Empowered Spell
>
> When you roll damage for a spell...

etc, etc.

Note that none of them state *"When you cast a **sorcerer** spell"*.